# Theoretical questions about Linux nanosleep and processes

Tags: linux

I have 2 theoretical questions related to Linux system programming in C about nanosleep and process destruction.

So, the first one:

It is possible to make 97% CPU load just by using nanosleep. For example, let's consider a for-loop that iterates 50 times with a delay of 1 second, on a child process. The delay is obtained using nanosleep. What I observed, on a devboard with Debian Linux, is that after somewhere between 15 and 20 iterations, nanosleep blocks  and CPU load is 90 % ( I used top to see the value).

The second question is somehow related to the first one. With the same code, 
a for-loop running 50 times on a child process I observed that when nanosleep blocks ( freeze) at a 90% CPU load the child process become a zombie process. 
It's a kernel mechanism that tries to kill a process that is using too much the CPU?

Again, sorry that I can't post the code, it's not mine... But I found curios this 2 cases and I didn't find something about on Internet, or I didn't know how to search. I just want to know, theoretically if it's possible to have 90% CPU load just using nanosleep, and secondly if the kernel have a safety mechanism that tries to kill processes that use too much the CPU.

I'm interested to find some opinions about this cases, maybe recommended alternative functions.

PS:I don't want to see comments that are asking for source code since this question is just theoretically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert but I assume that if your kernel kills the process cause it's consuming too much resources it will depend solely on the distro you're using.

About the use of CPU, theoretically you could continously get processes into the CPU and just sleep them. In this case the OS will be dispatching the processes from CPU to lock queue and back (Overhead), and depending on the type of queuing your distro uses to dispatch processes (Round Robin, queues with aging, etc, I can't remember right now where you can set this parameter) it could eventually starve other processes

Anyway this is not a C related question just OS

Answer (score 1):

Your question makes no sense (sorry).

1. If `nanosleep` blocks, it won't use any CPU, because it will be blocking, i.e. waiting in the kernel for something else to happen. That's what blocking means.
2. For a process to be using 100% CPU, it must be busy waiting.
3. If it's busywaiting, and calling `nanosleep`, we can conclude that each call to nanosleep is of very short duration.
4. An alternative explanation is it's using a large amount of CPU doing something else, and only very occasionally calling `nanosleep`, or there is more than one thread running, and a thread other than the one calling `nanosleep` is using lots of CPU.